# The memory dump of a process by using GDB inside a bash script - errors, problems

Tags: bash, memory, fifo, gdb

I want to dump some program's memory segment to a file. Because the working time of my program is milliseconds, I use **named pipe** to stop its execution and dump its memory content by `gdb` meanwhile. The script is working in some cases, but isn't in others: errors appear when I want to redirect output to some filter programs to format it, as well when `--nw`, `--nh` options are added.

**The question:** What causes these errors and why I can't get the script to work with `--nw`, `--nh` options added?

I will demonstrate the problem with a simplified example:

**my_program.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    puts("one two three");
    return 0;
}
```

**script.sh**

```
function find_stack_addr {
    read stack_start stack_end <<< $(awk '
    /\[stack\]/ {split($1, stack_maps, "-")}

    END {
        stack_start = "0x" stack_maps[1]
        stack_end = "0x" stack_maps[2]

        print stack_start, stack_end
    }' $1)
}

function dump_mem {
    ./my_program y y y > named_pipe &
    pid=$!

    find_stack_addr "/proc/${pid}/maps"

    sudo gdb --batch --pid "$pid" -ex "dump memory dumps/stack_${1}.dump $stack_start $stack_end"
    echo "$pid $stack_start $stack_end"
}

mkfifo named_pipe

for i in {1..3}; do
   dump_mem "$i"
done

rm named_pipe
```

**Result**

```
12798 0x7ffc5a875000 0x7ffc5a896000
12806 0x7ffc5a875000 0x7ffc5a896000
12814 0x7ffc5a875000 0x7ffc5a896000
```

and

```
dumps/
├── stack_1.dump
├── stack_2.dump
└── stack_3.dump
```

I want to redirect the `for` loop output to `column` program with headers added, so I change the `for` loop to this:

```
for i in {1..3}; do
   dump_mem "$i"
done | sed '1  i\pid stack_start stack_end' | column -t
```

and get errors (also the script doesn't finish):

```
/home/minimax/.gdbinit:4: Error in sourced command file:
Cannot enable the TUI when output is not a terminal
47  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/open64.c: No such file or directory.
```

It is clear that the problem is caused by redirection to a pipe instead of `stdin` and my `.gdbinit` file settings, so I add two options to the `gdb` command:

```
  --nh               Do not read ~/.gdbinit.
  --nw               Do not use the GUI interface.
```

Now, the `gdb` command is:

```
sudo gdb --nw --nh --batch --pid "$pid" -ex "dump memory dumps/stack_${1}.dump $stack_start $stack_end"
```

Then, the `TUI` error  disappears, but the `No such file or directory` doesn't:

```
47  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/open64.c: No such file or directory.
47  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/open64.c: No such file or directory.
47  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/open64.c: No such file or directory.
```

I try the first `for` loop with this `gdb` command (`--nw --nh` option added) and also get errors, though the script works and results are echoed.

```
0x00007f4dab824d9e in __libc_open64 (file=0x55da21e2e9a0 "named_pipe", oflag=577) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/open64.c:47
47  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/open64.c: No such file or directory.
13130 0x7ffcada58000 0x7ffcada79000      #<--- the script's output
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround - redirection of `GDB`'s output to `/dev/stdout`. The logic is following - if `GDB` works fine while its output is connected to the terminal, then it is needed to give him this connection. In this case, there are no errors.

In my case `/dev/stdout` points to `/dev/pts`:

```
$ ls -l /dev/stdout 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Oct  9 10:10 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1

$ ls -l /proc/self/fd/1
lrwx------ 1 minimax minimax 64 Oct  9 15:00 /proc/self/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/11
```

**Fixed code**

```
function dump_mem {
    ./my_program y y y > named_pipe &
    pid=$!

    find_stack_addr "/proc/${pid}/maps"

    sudo gdb --batch --pid "$pid" -ex "dump memory dumps/stack_${1}.dump $stack_start $stack_end" > /dev/stdout

    echo "$pid $stack_start $stack_end"
    cat named_pipe > /dev/null
}
```